# Multivariate regression on metric spaces

Tags: classification, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a collection of neurons from different parts of the brain. Call this the "test" set.

To these neurons I can associate a morphology measurement, which is an element of a metric space $X$, and an electrophysiology measurement, which is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Given a neuron not in the test set, I would like to predict what part of the brain it comes from. This is a categorical regression problem. Let's say there are three categories corresponding to different parts of the brain. Then I want to give a regression function $X \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \{ A, B, C\}$ from the known data.

What techniques exist to help me solve this problem? Since $X$ is a metric space,  I can apply techniques such as (possibly weighted) nearest neighbors. But I don't know how to integrate the data for $X$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Would it be possible to define an integrated metric space where the distance between points combines information from both the morphology variable and the electrophysiology vector? What is a principled way of doing this?

Comment: Put a metric on the product space, $X\times \mathbb R^n?$ The [product metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have a product metric space. It makes sense to [define a metric on the product space that metrizes the product space in the product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric), which [behaves about as you would expect for a finite product.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology)

A candidate for a product metric is just to take the $\ell_p$ norm, $p\in\left[1,\infty\right)$, of each individual metric distance. That is:

$$
d_{
X\times\mathbb R^n
}\left(
\left(x_1, r_1\right),
\left(x_2, r_2\right)
\right):=\left\vert\left\vert
\left(
d_X\left(x_1, x_2\right),
d_{\mathbb R^n}\left(r_1, r_2\right)
\right)
\right\vert\right\vert_p\space\space\forall\space\space
x_1, x_2\in X, r_1, r_2\in\mathbb R^n
$$

(I suspect that a weighted norm also yields a metric space and that proving this is rather easy, but I have not shown this (at least not since college analysis).)

You now have a metric on your product space to measure the distance for the KNN model.

Comment: This solution occurred to me as well. I am looking for a solution which would be sensitive to the relevant information which is provided by each argument, integrating their contributions in a principled way. The average distance between points in one space could be much larger than the other. Then I could rescale all distances or apply some kind of log(1+x) transform to make the extreme distances smaller but now I am choosing very ad hoc solutions. I am interested to see a solution which has some theory of integration of information.